# Create a live template for Java in Intellij

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

I would like to create a template to automatically make my Javadoc documentation when I create a method. For example if I create a method:

```
protected User createUser_1P(String uname, String[] stocks) throws ElementAlreadyExists {
    ...
    return u;
}
```

I would like the template to generate something like this:

```
 /*
 * @param uname user name
 * @param stocks list of stocks
 * @return User
 * @throws ElementAlreadyExists
 */
```

Any help will be apreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To generate JavaDoc for your method in IntelliJ all you need to do is to type `/**` on the line above the method definition and hit Enter.

For your method the following JavaDoc will be generated:

```
/**
 *
 * @param uname
 * @param stocks
 * @return
 * @throws ElementAlreadyExists
 */
protected User createUser_1P(String uname, String[] stocks) throws ElementAlreadyExists {
    ...
    return u;
}
```

Mind you that IntelliJ does not provide with any descriptions, you will have to fill them out.